# Why doesn't a process get triggered multiple times

Tags: process-builder

Conceptual question. I have a process in process builder that triggers whenever a record is update. The process launches a flow. The flow updates the record. Why then doesn't the process trigger again? I know there is a checkbox I can click to make that happen. So does that mean there is a setting that checks to see if this record has been activated already for this update.

Comment: I don't know the internals of how the Process Builder recursion protection works. My guess would be it maintains a collection of all the record Ids that have already been processed through the corresponding flow. Then if they come up again and recursion isn't enabled they get skipped.